# Can the SASS --watch command execute bash scripts?

Tags: bash, command-line, sass

For example, whenever I update a .scss file, I want the SASS to automatically execute this line of code:

```
rsync -vru . root@mydomain.com:/var/www/vhosts/mysite.com/httpdocs/assets/css
```

In other words, whenever SASS recompiles the .scss files, it would also upload them to my site.

Comment: Sass is just for compiling Sass code into CSS.

Comment: But it has a --watch command that automatically compiles the code when changes are made to any files. I'm wondering if its possible to run a simple script when that happens.

Comment: And what I already told you still stands.  The --watch flag tells it to continuously watch a file or directory and recompile whenever changes are made.  That's all it can do.

Comment: I'm not arguing with what you said. But if the watch command can execute the `style.scss style.css` script when a change is made, it is executing a callback function. All I'm asking is if it's possible to add another command to the callback, even if it involves peeking under the hood of `--watch`

Comment: Why didn't you peek under the hood before you asked this question?  Using `sass --help` would have given you your answer.

Comment: Perhaps there's some way not explicitly defined in the --help documentation.

Comment: To be fair, this is a valid question and not unreasonable to assume there may be a complete callback or similar behaviour. Sharing knowledge is the point of SO; so telling people to view the source is not hugely helpful.